# Converting geographic units with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, units

I am trying to compare a set of point features to the centroid of a single feature polygon using ArcPy. The problem is that the polygon generates a set of XY coordinates in meters, whereas the set of points generates a set of XY coordinates in decimal degrees.

Is there anyway to ensure consistency?

Using some variations of `SHAPE@XY@DECIMALDEGREES` threw errors. When I do the following:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("prim_catch_dissolved", ["TR", "SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
```

I get the results in meters, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/arcgis-arcpy-python-how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-projected-point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`spatial_reference` parameter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to reproject on-the-fly.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("prim_catch_dissolved", ["TR", "SHAPE@XY"], spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")) as cursor:
    # Do interesting things here
```